# i have problem to responsive layout use ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

- hello! I need my layouts to be responsive. I choose ConstraintLayout for this case but imageviews in my ConstraintLayout in small size and large size became irregular.
  in tablet, my imageviews became too small and in small size is too large. my XML is here I think I cant set all true attributes in this layout. If someone guides me,  helped me a lot*

  ```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/shopbtn"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/shop"
      android:fontFamily="casual"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="normal|bold"
      android:typeface="serif"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35000002" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/exitbtn"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/prew"
      android:fontFamily="casual"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="normal|bold"
      android:typeface="serif"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/shopbtn"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.785"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/startbtn"

      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/play"
      android:fontFamily="casual"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="normal|bold"
      android:typeface="serif"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.275"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/shopbtn"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35000002" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/adamkhar"
      android:layout_width="94dp"
      android:layout_height="117dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.625"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/pico" />
  ```

Comment: do you have a screenshot of the actual rendering problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `50dp` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

You can ise [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

**Here is an example using `ConstraintLayout`:**

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/shopbtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rose"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/startbtn"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exitbtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exitbtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rose"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/shopbtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/shopbtn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shopbtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startbtn"

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rose"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/shopbtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/shopbtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shopbtn" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/adamkhar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shopbtn"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>*
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Please notice that this is just an example and if you want to change the size of your views just change the value of `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent`.